# Show Field if Radio Button is Selected

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to get the Website URL field on [this page](http://myfrugaltech.com/dev/savoo/register/) to display only when the previous question has the radio button "Yes" selected. I've searched and tried a few code examples, but they aren't working. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="editfield">
<div class="radio">
    <span class="label">Do you have your own website? (required)</span>
    <div id="field_8"><label><input type="radio" name="field_8" id="option_9" value="Yes"> Yes</label><label><input type="radio" name="field_8" id="option_10" value="No"> No</label></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="editfield">
<label for="field_19">Website URL </label>
<input type="text" name="field_19" id="field_19" value="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the corresponding html and javascript along with your question.

Comment: I also noticed that you can were able to use jquery in your question a little bit ago. Is that available here as well?

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the HTML being used for the fields. Yes, jQuery is available here as well.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that you initally put the javascript I gave you at the top of the page. If you are going to do this then you need to encapsulate the code in a jquery `$(document).ready(function(){ });`. You only need to use a document ready when your html follows after the javascript.

```
$(function() {
    // place code here
});
```

However, in this scenario I have created another alternative that will be better, but do not forget that you have to initially set the web url div as hidden. Also, I highly recommend that you set better control ids; it will make your javascript easier to understand.

```
$('input[name=field_8]').on("click",  function(){
    var $div_WebUrl = $('#field_19').closest('.editfield');

    if($('input[name=field_8]').index(this) == 0)
        $div_WebUrl.show();
    else
        $div_WebUrl.hide();
});​
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pNrjk/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I've installed the code on the site, but it didn't work. Wondering if I'm doing anything wrong. Could you take a look please? http://myfrugaltech.com/dev/savoo/register/

Comment: @MitchellWischmann First of all you need to have the div containing the web address initially hidden via display:none as shown in my demo.

Comment: @MitchellWischmann I have updated my answer based on what I saw on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a little example:

```
<div class="editfield">
<div class="radio">
    <span class="label">Do you have your own website? (required)</span>
    <div id="field_8"><label><input type="radio" name="field_8" id="option_9" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='block'"> Yes</label><label><input type="radio" name="field_8" id="option_10" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('divUrl').style.display='none'"> No</label></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="editfield" id="divUrl" style="display:none">
<label for="field_19">Website URL </label>
<input type="text" name="field_19" id="field_19" value="" />
</div>​
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EQkzE/

Note: I have updated the div to include a style, cause I do not know what your css class looks like. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure JS Solution:

```
document.getElementById("field_19").parentNode.style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("option_9").onclick = toggleURLInput;
document.getElementById("option_10").onclick = toggleURLInput;

function toggleURLInput(){
    document.getElementById("field_19").parentNode.style.display = (document.getElementById("option_9").checked)? "block" : "none";
}
```

Not a very dynamic solution, but [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/45sZT/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will bind the click event to a simple function to look at the radio button and show the other div.

```
$('#option_9').on('click', function() { 
  if ($('#option_9').is(':checked')) { 
    $('#field_19').closest('.editfield').show();
  } else {
    $('#field_19').closest('.editfield').hide();
  }
});
```

[Run sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/EQkzE/9/)

Comment: Just so you know, live is deprecated and has been replaced by on.