# Multiple sets of radio buttons with optional text field

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to create multiple sets of an optional text field after the user selects the "Yes" radio button. Now, I have created radio buttons and an optional text field for 'Physical Disability'. I want to create another set for 'Health Issues'.

When I create another function with the same name, only the most recent function works, the first function does not work. I understand that the last function kinda overrides the earlier functions.

The code is below:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title></title>
    <style></style>
        </head>
        <body>

      {{-- javascript code for radio button and text field for Physical Disability --}}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowHideDiv() {
            var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
            var dvPhyDis = document.getElementById("dvPhyDis");
            dvPhyDis.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }
    </script>

{{-- javascript code for radio button and text field for Health Issue --}}
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowHideDiv() {
        var chkYes = document.getElementById("chkYes");
        var dvHealthIss = document.getElementById("dvHealthIss");
        dvHealthIss.style.display = chkYes.checked ? "block" : "none";
    }
</script>


        @extends('layout.basiclayout')

        @section('content')

        <h1>ADDITIONAL INFORMATION</h1>
           {!! Form::open(['url' => 'page8/submit']) !!}

        <span><b>Do you have any Physical Disability?</b></span>
        <label for="chkYes">
            <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPhyDis" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" value="Yes"/> Yes
        </label>
        <label for="chkNo">
            <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPhyDis" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" value="No"/> No
        </label>

        <div id="dvPhyDis" style="display: none">
            <b>Please provide more details:</b>
            <input type="text" name="txtPhyDis" size="75px">
        </div>

<br>

<span><b>Do you have any Health Issue?</b></span>
<label for="chkYes">
    <input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkHealthIss" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkHealthIss" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
    No
</label>

<div id="dvHealthIss" style="display: none">
    <b>Please provide more details:</b>
    <input type="text" name="txtHealthIss" size="75px">    
</div>
<br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                          {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    </div>

        {!! Form::close() !!}
        </body>
        </html>
        @endsection
```

Image:
[Result of radio buttons and text field in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh7UA.png)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Something like this? Click on Live Demo to see.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12290711/3254405

Comment: Yes, like the Live Demo. The issue is I want to create another question with the radio buttons and optional text field.

Comment: Dhruv Aggarwal - 
My question is I want to create another question with the radio buttons and optional text field but I cannot.

Comment: why not just change the name of function